# Getting System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException from a single client

Tags: wcf, abort

We have a customer in the field that installed our client app on a new machine. When they try and login; which calls a WCF web service; they get the following error:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException

"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted."

They installed on another machine, and had no problem. The app is installed at several locations with no problems.

Any idea why it does not work on a single machine? The machine is running Windows 7, but the app is running on other machines with Windows 7.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are you making your calls to the service?

From what you've said it sounds a bit like the service call is failing and somehow you are trying to make a method call on the object that implements IChannel, i.e., it's in a using block and the dispose method is blowing up.

Post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
try {
   userService = Services.UserServiceClient();
   LoggedInUser.User = userService.Login(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text); 
   userService.Close();
}
catch... { }
```

But, like I said above, it is working on several other computers with no problems. Just not working on a single computer. Was thinking maybe some .net lib needs installed or something.